# Spring Boot serving an m3u8 playlist

Tags: java, spring-boot, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, playlist

I'm trying to serve an m3u8 playlist through Spring Boot. I have a running ffmpeg process that is transcoding a multicast in real-time and sending the files to /src/resources/public/output.m3u8. I see the playlist updating and the new .ts files being generated correctly however when trying to watch the stream in a video player, it only plays a certain amount of video. Is there a way to properly serve up a running playlist in Java instead of serving it statically?

EDIT: When starting a basic http server with python `python3 -m http.server`, I'm able to view the stream perfectly fine. Is there a Spring Boot way to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 4.1 your approach will work there is no issue in it. Here below is another approach in case if you want to look

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/VMS-49001/playlist/{listName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> testphoto() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/no_image.jpg");

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();


    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: When watching the playlist it doesn't seem to be grabbing the updated playlist and ts files though. So it just plays a single video instead of a stream.